# How to make a button list to show two columns on mobile?

Tags: html, css, list

I'm working on a webapp and the main page has 4 buttons. They are flex and not ordered in columns. But I'd like them to show in a minimum of two columns when you go on mobile, maybe by resizing itself. I've tried many different things but I couldn't find anything, maybe it's because I'm still unexperienced with HTML/CSS (third day using it) and I'd like some help!

Code:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  height: 40vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
}



@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  li {
    height: 30vh;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 480px) {
  li {
    height: 80vh;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  li {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.btn {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-color: black;
    padding: 14px 28px;
    font-size: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 4px;
    overflow-x: flex;
    flex: auto;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="btn uno"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn due"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn tre"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn sei"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Visual representation:

[image]

Comment: please add also your CSS into the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to `<ul>` and do this using css `grid` layout and using 2 media queries,

```
@media (min-width: 10px) {
  .cards { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .cards { grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); }
}
```

Full code:

```css
.cards {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 10px) {
  .cards { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .cards { grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); }
}

li {
  height: 40vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.btn {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-color: black;
    padding: 14px 28px;
    font-size: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 4px;
    overflow-x: flex;
    flex: auto;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<ul class="cards">
  <li>
    <button class="btn uno"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn due"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn tre"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn sei"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You may try to adjust the media queries (`min-width` property) to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap :

```html
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="container">
    <ul class="row">
      <li class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <button class="btn uno"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></button>
      </li>
      <li class="col-12 col-sm-6" >
        <button class="btn due"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
      </li>
      <li class="col-12 col-sm-6" >
        <button class="btn tre"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></button>
      </li>
      <li class="col-12 col-sm-6" >
        <button class="btn sei"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

This make you flexible using COL, GRID and ROW.